# How to check if Rss has been updated when there's no Etag support

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I've tried this code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
import feedparser 
import time


c = feedparser.parse('http://www.tsa-algerie.com/feed/')
constID = c['entries'][0].id
print c['entries'][0]['title']
while True:
    time.sleep(300) 
    if constID != c['entries'][0].id:
        print c['entries'][0].title
        constID = c['entries'][0].id
```

Answer (score 1):

RSS feeds are "dumb" and by default, they *won't propagate updates*, which means that, if you need to know if a feed has been updated, you'll have to fetch it yourself, and compare 2 successive versions.

There are protocols, on top of RSS which may help, including [PubSubHubbub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) which lets you subscribe to an existing hub to be notified (via Webhooks) when a feed has been updated. [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com/) provides a default hub which works with any feed.